# Getting 'Couldn't resolve host' error while updating git in windows

Tags: windows, git, ssh, gitlab

I'm trying to update the `git` in my windows system.
I'm using this cmd:

```
git update-git-for-windows
```

That cmd returns below error:

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: gitforwindows.org

Host is working in browser, is this a bug in latest versions of git or is this happening because I'm in corporate network?

Comment: That's a DNS issue, not anything specifically related to Git. Check with your corporate network's admins.